# itterate through multiple URLs with BS4 - and store results into a csv-format

Tags: python, linux, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hi there i am currently working on a little tiny sraper - and i am putting some pieces together
i have an URL which holds record of so called digital hubs:  see https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view

i want to export the 700 regords in (to) a csv-format: that is -into a excel-spreadsheet. so far so good:

i have made some first experiments - which look pretty  nice.

see

```
# Python program to print all heading tags
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
# scraping a the content
url_link = 'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view'
request = requests.get(url_link)
 
Soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
 
# creating a list of all common heading tags
heading_tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"]
for tags in Soup.find_all(heading_tags):
    print(tags.name + ' -> ' + tags.text.strip())
```

which delivers:

```
h1 -> Smart Specialisation Platform
h1 -> Digital Innovation Hubs

Digital Innovation Hubs
h2 -> Bavarian Robotic Network (BaRoN) Bayerisches Robotik-Netzwerk, BaRoN
h4 -> Contact Data
h4 -> Description
h4 -> Link to national or regional initiatives for digitising industry
h4 -> Market and Services
h4 -> Organization
h4 -> Evolutionary Stage
h4 -> Geographical Scope
h4 -> Funding
h4 -> Partners
h4 -> Technologies
```

i want to get the data set : https://s3platform.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool: i need to itterate 700 urls see
[image]

https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view
https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/17865/view
https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1416/view

Well for the itterating-part i think i can go this way to iterate through multiple URLs, which I can define in advance, using Requests and BeautifulSoup: Attached is what I have so far, i.e. trying to put the URls in a list....

```
import requests
import bs4
URLs = ["https://example-url-1.com", "https://example-url-2.com"]
result = requests.get(URLs)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

Well - to be frank: I'm also looking for a way to include a interval delay so as not to SPAM the server. So i could go so:

```
import requests
import bs4
import sleep from time
URLs = ['https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view',
        'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/17865/view',
        'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1416/view'
        ]

def getPage(url):
    print('Indexing {0}......'.format(url))
    result = requests.get(url)
    print('Url Indexed...Now pausing 50secs before next ')
    sleep(50)
    return result

results = map(getPage, URLs)
for result in results:
    # soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
    print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

and now for the parser-part: parse the data eg from here as a example: https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view'
r = requests.get(url)
html_as_string = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_as_string, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('p'):
    print (link.text)
```

resultat- pretty awesome but unsorted - i want to store all the results in a csv-format - that is into a excelsheet with the following columns:

> Digital Innovation Hubs h2 -> Bavarian Robotic Network (BaRoN)
> Bayerisches Robotik-Netzwerk, BaRoN h4 -> Contact Data h4 ->
> Description h4 -> Link to national or regional initiatives for
> digitising industry h4 -> Market and Services h4 -> Organization h4 ->
> Evolutionary Stage h4 -> Geographical Scope h4 -> Funding h4 ->
> Partners h4 -> Technologies

see

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view'
r = requests.get(url)
html_as_string = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_as_string, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('p'):
    print (link.text)
```

see the results:

> Click on the following link if you want to propose a change of this
> HUB
>
> You need an EU Login account for request proposals for editions or
> creations of new hubs. If you already have an ECAS account, you don't
> have to create a new EU Login account. In EU Login, your credentials
> and personal data remain unchanged. You can still access the same
> services and applications as before. You just need to use your e-mail
> address for logging in. If you don't have an EU Login account please
> use the following link. you can create one by clicking on the Create
> an account hyperlink. If you already have a user account for EU Login
> please login via https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/cas/login   Sign in New
> user? Create an account Coordinator (University) Robotic Competence
> Center of Technical University of Munich, TUM CC Coordinator website
> http://www6.in.tum.de/en/home/ Year Established 2017 Location
> Schleißheimer Str. 90a, 85748, Garching bei München (Germany) Website
> http://www.robot.bayern Social Media
>
> Contact information  Adam Schmidt  adam.schmidt@tum.de  +49 (0)89
> 289-18064
>
> Year Established 2017 Location Schleißheimer Str. 90a, 85748, Garching
> bei München (Germany) Website http://www.robot.bayern Social Media
>
> Contact information Description BaRoN is an initiative bringing
> together several actors in Bavaria: the TUM Robotics Competence Center
> founded within the HORSE project, Bavarian Research Alliance (BayFOR),
> ITZB (Projektträger Bayern) and Bayerische Patentallianz, the latter
> three being members of the Bavarian Research and Innovation Agency) in
> order to facilitate the process of robotizing Bavarian manufacturing
> sector. In its current form it is an informal alliance of established
> institutions with a vast experience in the field of bringing and
> facilitating innovation in Bavaria. The mission of the network is to
> make Bavaria the forerunner of the digitalized and robotized European
> industry. The mission is realized by offering services ranging from
> providing the technological expertise, access to the robotic
> equipment, IPR advice and management, and funding facilitation to
> various entities of the Bavarian manufacturing ecosystem – start-ups,
> SMEs, research institutes, universities and other institutions
> interested in embracing the Industry 4.0 revolution. BaRoN verbindet
> mehrere Bayerische Akteure mit einem gemeinsamen Ziel – die
> Robotisierung des Bayerischen produzierenden Gewerbes voranzutreiben.
> OP Bayern ERDF 2014-2020   Enhancing the competitiveness of SMEs
> through the creation and the extension of advanced capacities for
> product and service developments and through internationalisation
> initiatives Budget 1.4B€

well to sume up: it am getting back a awful and unsorted datachunk with BS4 - how to clean up with Pandas so that i have a cean table with the following columns

```
h1 -> Smart Specialisation Platform
h1 -> Digital Innovation Hubs

Digital Innovation Hubs
h2 -> Bavarian Robotic Network (BaRoN) Bayerisches Robotik-Netzwerk, BaRoN
h4 -> Contact Data
h4 -> Description
h4 -> Link to national or regional initiatives for digitising industry
h4 -> Market and Services
h4 -> Organization
h4 -> Evolutionary Stage
h4 -> Geographical Scope
h4 -> Funding
h4 -> Partners
h4 -> Technologies
```

**update:** thanks to Tim Roberts i have seen that we have the f ollowing combination

```
class: hubCard
class: hubCardTitle
class: hubCardContent
class: infoLabel >Description>
<p> Text - data - content <p>
```

with this - we can extend the parsing job step by step. Many thanks to you Tim!

[image]

that said - i am just trying to get the data for the other fields of interest - eg. the description text which starts like so:

> BaRoN is an initiative bringing together several actors in Bavaria:
> the TUM Robotics Competence Center founded within the HORSE project,
> Bavarian Research Alliance (BayFOR), ITZB (Projektträger Bayern)

I applied the ideas of you, Tim to the code. - but it does not work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')

# The name of the hub is in the <h4> tag.

hubname = soup.find('h4').text

# All contact info is within a <div class='hubCard'>.

description = soup.find("div", class_="hubCardContent")

cardinfo = {}

# Grab all the <p> tags inside that div.  The infoLabel class marks
# the section header.

for data in description.find_all('p'):
    if 'infoLabel' in data.attrs.get('class', []):
        Description = data.text
        cardinfo[Description] = []
    else:
        cardinfo[Description].append( data.text )

# The contact info is in a <div> inside that div.

#for data in contact.find_all('div', class_='infoMultiValue'):
#    cardinfo['Description'].append( data.text)

print("---")
print(hubname)
print("---")
pprint(cardinfo)
```

it allways gives back the content information - but not the data that i am looking for - the text of the description:
i am doing something wrong...

Comment: Well, YOU need to read through the HTML of the pages you are fetching, in order to know how to locate the information you want.  You need to have the data in a nice clean state BEFORE you move it into pandas.

Comment: good day dear Tim - many thanks. This is pretty helpful. Does here the list of columns help that i have added to the end of the posting!? 
I would be more than happy if you can give me two hints - one how to itterate over the approx 700 URLs - whith mechanize or request - and how to ge the tidy and clean state before adding the data to pandas . many thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can give you a start.  You HAVE to dig into the HTML to find the key markers for the information you want.  I'm sensing that you want the title, and the contact information.  The title is in an `<h2>` tag, the only such tag on the page.  The contact info is within a `<div class='hubCard'>` tag, so we can grab that and pull out the pieces.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://s3platform-legacy.jrc.ec.europa.eu/digital-innovation-hubs-tool/-/dih/1096/view'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')

# The name of the hub is in the <h2> tag.

hubname = soup.find('h2').text

# All contact info is within a <div class='hubCard'>.

contact = soup.find("div", class_="hubCard")

cardinfo = {}

# Grab all the <p> tags inside that div.  The infoLabel class marks
# the section header.

for data in contact.find_all('p'):
    if 'infoLabel' in data.attrs.get('class', []):
        title = data.text
        cardinfo[title] = []
    else:
        cardinfo[title].append( data.text )

# The contact info is in a <div> inside that div.

for data in contact.find_all('div', class_='infoMultiValue'):
    cardinfo['Contact information'].append( data.text)

print("---")
print(hubname)
print("---")
pprint(cardinfo)
```

Output:

```
---
 Bavarian Robotic Network (BaRoN) Bayerisches Robotik-Netzwerk, BaRoN
---
{'Contact information': [' Adam Schmidt',
                         ' adam.schmidt@tum.de',
                         ' +49 (0)89 289-18064'],
 'Coordinator (University)': ['',
                              'Robotic Competence Center of Technical '
                              'University of Munich, TUM CC'],
 'Coordinator website': ['http://www6.in.tum.de/en/home/\n'
                         '\t\t\t\t\t\n'
                         '\t\t\t\t\t\n'
                         '\t\t\t\t\t'],
 'Location': ['Schleißheimer Str. 90a, 85748, Garching bei München (Germany)'],
 'Social Media': ['\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t'],
 'Website': ['http://www.robot.bayern'],
 'Year Established': ['2017']}
```

Comment: Thanks to you Tim Roberts: i have seen that we have the f ollowing combination
`class: hubCard
class: hubCardTitle
class: hubCardContent
class: infoLabel >Description>
<p> Text - data - content <p>`

With this - i can extend the parser - since we have more infos on the site... Many many thanks to you. This is awesome.  BTW.- the itteration over the set of pages we can do with some nice request lines...

Comment: btw. Each of the data sets on the page - has got the following items... infoLabel, and InfoMultiValue - so, if i want to gather all the content of the page - i have to extend your given example with similar sets of lines that get the according sets like
`h4 -> Contact Data
h4 -> Description
h4 -> Market and Services
h4 -> Organization
h4 -> Evolutionary Stage `

is this correct!? - With that i can continue to put all the data subsequently to panda!?
Tim - many many thanks for your hints




`class: infoLabel >Description>
<p> Text - data - content <p>
class: infoMultiValue`

Comment: I think you have the concept now.  Why would you take this into pandas?  I can see creating a CSV or an Excel spreadsheet, but what does pandas gain you?  There's no numerical information here.

Comment: Hello dear Tim - many thanks for the quick answer. Its great. And yes. I do not need pands here - it would be great to have the dataset in CSV_format that is - in a Excel-spreadsheet. Many thanks for all you did!